# pod lint compile my swift code without taking #define in account

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have an SDK with 2 targets (iOS + WatchExtension) that I want to push to cocoapods but when I lint my podspec I get this error :

```
 - ERROR | [iOS] [Proj/WatchExtension] Proj/Proj/Sender.swift:286:33: error: use of unresolved identifier 'BackgroundTask'
```

To make my sdk compatible with WatchExtension, I have in my project some code like this :

```
#if !WATCH_EXT
/* BackgroundTask Class that use UIKit stuff*/
#endif
```

On my podspec I have this :

```
s.subspec 'WatchExtension' do |watchos|
    watchos.compiler_flag           = "-D WATCH_EXT"
    watchos.source_files            = "Proj/Proj/*.{h,m,swift}"
    watchos.exclude_files           = "Proj/Proj/BackgroundTask.{swift}" #Class that use UIKit stuff
    watchos.frameworks              = "CoreData", "CoreFoundation", "WatchKit", "UIKit", "CoreTelephony", "SystemConfiguration"
end
```

I tried with the prefix_header_contents flag but with the same result, the `#if !WATCH_EXT` keep being ignored

Answer (score 0):

ok found my problem, I replaced `watchos.compiler_flag = "-D WATCH_EXT"` by `watchos.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS' => '-DWATCH_EXT' }`